# How to let less2css compile all files once one of the less file is saved?

Tags: css, compilation, less, sublimetext2

I have style.less which import "page.less". When something is changed in page.less, I have to turn to file style.less and save to let less2css compile so that the changes will take effect otherwise it doesn't because page.less is imported! So is there a way to let less2css compile all files when one of them is changed?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're already using the [LESS-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396973/how-to-let-less2css-compile-all-files-once-one-of-the-less-file-is-saved) you can use [SublimOnSaveBuild](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeOnSaveBuild). This would also work in other scopes.

Alternatively, there's a LESS-only [package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/smart%20less%20build) for Sublime Text as well.